# Load two json model at one controller in Sapui5

Tags: json, controller, sapui5

I have two json data.When ı tried this code , chrome console only showing only last loaded json model.  How can ı load two json in one controller ? This my code which I tried.

```
   var view = this.getView();
    var model2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    model2.loadData("model/x.json");
    var model3 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    model3.loadData("model/y.json");
    view.setModel(model3);
    view.setModel(model2)
```

And this.

```
    var view = this.getView();
    var model2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    model2.loadData("model/x.json");
    model2.loadData("model/y.json");
    view.setModel(model2)
```

Comment: The answer of @herrlock should be the right answer, please indicate it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The method [`setModel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#setModel) takes two arguments. The first one is the actual model you want to set, the second one is the name that the model is stored with. Generally you can use `setModel(oModel)`, then you store that model with the name `undefined`. That is what you do, you set one model to the name undefined and overwrite it with the second one. To store both you have to specify a name for at least one of the models.
So if you call

```
view.setModel(model1, "bar");
view.setModel(model2, "foo");
```

you can get them with

```
var barmodel = view.getModel("bar");
var foomodel = view.getModel("foo");
```

Do not forget to adjust your binding by adding the model name as prefix, e.g. bar>.

Comment: Thank you herrlock, this is good information for me but not worked my project. I am getting the same error.

Comment: There is no console error.When ı debug project , view content  seems to be empty

Comment: That is clear! If you use named models you need to use the model name in the binding, e.g. bar>/Entities instead of /Entities.

Answer (score 0):

The method **loadData** has a parameter **bMerge** which indicates the response from the server should be merged into the existing data instead of overwritting the data. Please check the [API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData).

Comment: bMerge is loading data but not keeping changing. When ı try update one json file  , other json file not showing again